# resource manager and node manager not starting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

my question might be duplicated, i had searched similar question here but it didn't solve my problem.

so i'm new in hadoop, now i'm setting up multinode cluster which is 1 master and 2 slaves. when i run `jps` command on master node, my terminal shows this

```
3250 - DataNode
3090 - NameNode
4099 - jps
3498 - SecondaryNameNode
```

and when i run `jps` command on slaves node, my terminal shows this

```
3896 - DataNode
4684 - jps
4111 - SecondaryNameNode
```

according to this tutorial [link](https://intellitech.pro/tutorial-hadoop-multi-node-installation/), my master node would have the this output

```
jps
namenode
secondary namenode
resource manager
```

and my slaves node would have this

```
jps  
NodeManager
DataNode
```

so on master node there is no `resource manager` and on slaves node there is no `node manager`

**edit**

when i start `start-dfs.sh` command, the output of my terminal shows this

```
Starting namenodes on [HadoopMaster]
starting datanodes
starting secondary namenodes [farhan-master]
```

and when i start `start-yarn.sh` command, the output of my terminal shows this

```
starting resourcemanager
starting nodemanager
```

how do i solve this problem? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run the start-yarn script? Was it successful? You need to show us the log outputs of those processes (logs are output into your Hadoop folder). Jps just shows they are/aren't running, not why

Comment: also, you can't have two SecondaryNameNodes in a cluster.

Comment: i already run start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh. and all of it was successful @cricket_007

Comment: and i exactly following the tutorial, nothing missed.

Comment: Successful based on what? If a process isn't starting, it's not successful. Please add the logs of the resource manager to the question, not the output of the start scripts

Comment: I have the same problem, and within `~/hadoop-3.2.2/logs` folder, runing `cat hadoop-hadoop-resourcemanager-Sun.log` showing the port number 8088 is already used.   When I changed the port number to another number 8801 in the yarn-site.xml in the namenode and copied this yarn-site.xml file to other datanodes/secondarynamenode, then i run stop-all.sh and start-all.sh, the ResourceManager is back.